# Office365 user delta APIs

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, office365

This document explain how to use user delta APIs and get delta token. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users

But how many record changes will delta token call returns? Is there any limit?
Also if the number of records changed exceeds the limit, will all the records will be returned or we get nextLink in delta token call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the page size by using `$top`, and according to this [post](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4636), the default number is 100. If the number of records exceeds the limit, a `@odata.nextLink` will be returned for accessing more data. You can refer to this tutorial about the [paging(@odata.nextlink and $top)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)

**Update:**

Confirmed with azure support team, the answer is the `$top` parameter may not support `delta` because the expression in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview).
[image]

And we need to notice if we have the premission.
[image]

The azure support team suggest: If you want to know more about this api, you can send email to the contributors.
[image]

Comment: I don't think $top is supported in /users/delta API. You can find the difference by trying the API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview

User API : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=2
Delta API : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$top=2

Comment: Hi @kushi I test it in my side, I found the "$top" sometimes works fine but sometimes doesn't work. According to the document of this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#optional-query-parameters), it should supports the "$top" parameter. I will do some more research and get back.

Comment: @kushi According to some test, it should be some issue with this api. The "$top" parameter doesn't work every time(I mentioned it sometimes works fine just now because the number of response records coincidentally equal to the value of $top what I set). For this issue, you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), I will also do some research and get back if have any update.

Comment: Thanks @hury. Also Any idea what will be the maximum or default number of records returned using delta API?

Comment: @kushi It seems the default number is also different from the document shows. I'm checking with azure support team if there is a bug in this api. I will let you know if there is any update.

Comment: Hi @kushi I have confirmed with azure support team, the answer is not so reliable. I have updated my answer, please check~